# Loop for multiple buttons in Python, Kivy

Tags: python, loops, button, kivy

I have creating multiple buttons via for loop in Python/Kivy. I can't figureout how to implement for each button on_press and on_release function, so each button (having it's defined color) will come back to its original color after releasing.

Below You will find part of code in python and kivy.

Python:

```
class PrButton(GridLayout):

def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(PrButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.build_grid()

def build_grid(self):
    for i in hi_cat():
        btn = ButtonDD(text=i[0].upper())
        btn.background_color = i[1]
        self.ids[i[0]] = btn
        self.add_widget(btn)
```

kivy file:

```
<ButtonDD>
bold: True
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

```py
from kivymd.app import MDApp 
from kivy.lang import Builder 
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout 
from kivy.uix.button import Button 


KV = """
<MainWidget>:
    size : root.size 
    
 
"""


class MainWidget(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        
        for i in range(5):
            
            btn = Button(text = str(i))
            btn.bind(on_release = lambda i=i:self.clicked(i))
            self.add_widget(btn)
            
    
    def clicked(self,text):
        print(text)

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        
        Builder.load_string(KV)
    
        return MainWidget()

MainApp().run()
```

It is achieved by changing `lambda x: self.clicked()` To `lambda i=i:self.clicked()`

I've been stuck with this kind of problem for some time now.  But I got my answer recently. So I hope this helps you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).